# Python slice and delete function

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I do not understand the slice function. I want to delete all columns from a certain number.

```
data = np.delete(data, slice(1344,-1), axis = 1)
print(data.shape)
print(data[0,1340:1345])
data = np.delete(data,1344, axis =1 )
print(data.shape)
print(data[0,1340:1345])
```

If I do so, data.shape somehow does not delete the last element and therefore I get a '0' there which I have to delete in an additional step.

```
(200000, 1345)
[435 432 426 438   0]
(200000, 1344)
[435 432 426 438]
```

If I decrease the index by 1,

```
data = np.delete(data, slice(1343,-1), axis = 1)
print(data.shape)
print(data[0,1340:1345])
```

I still get a '0' at the end, but the number before is deleted.

```
(200000, 1344)
[435 432 426   0]
```

How can I get in a single line an array with size of (200000, 1344) with no 0 at the end, but the real number?

Comment: Slices and ranges don't include the last value. That's why `list(range(1, 10))` only returns the numbers from 1 to 9. Use `None` as the end of the slice to mean the very end. This is the default, so you can just say `slice(1344)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple 1d array:

```
In [170]: x=np.arange(10)    
In [171]: x[slice(5,-1)]
Out[171]: array([5, 6, 7, 8])
```

The slice by itself is:

```
In [172]: slice(5,-1)
Out[172]: slice(5, -1, None)
```

which is the equivalent of:

```
In [173]: x[5:-1]
Out[173]: array([5, 6, 7, 8])
```

To get values starting from the end:

```
In [174]: x[slice(None,5,-1)]
Out[174]: array([9, 8, 7, 6])
In [176]: x[:5:-1]
Out[176]: array([9, 8, 7, 6])
```

Or deleting:

```
In [177]: np.delete(x,slice(None,5,-1))
Out[177]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```